# TouchOpacity component set to position absolute unclickable in android

Tags: android, react-native, styles, react-native-svg-charts

I've created a custom dropdown using TouchOpacity component of react native as follows.

```
 <View style={dropDownStyle}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _switchTimeSpan('Day')}>
       <Text style={dropDownItemStyle}>Day</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _switchTimeSpan('Week')}>
       <Text style={dropDownItemStyle}>Week</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
```

The style is as follows.

```
  dropDownStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 80,
  },
  dropDownItemStyle: {
    marginTop: 5,
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
```

When pressed the TouchOpacity component doesn't trigger the onpress function. This issue only exists in android and not IOS.

Edit 1 : There is a areachart created use react-native-svg-charts which is being overlapped by the mentioned dropdown. However upon inspecting if the reason for the onPress not working could be because of zIndex issues i noticed that the mentioned dropdown is the top most component.

The code for the chart is the following.

**I am using react-native-svg-charts**

```
<View style={containerStyle}>
      <YAxis
        data={data}
        style={yAxisStyle}
        formatLabel={value => yAxisFormat(value)}
        contentInset={verticalContentInset}
        numberOfTicks={5}
        svg={axesSvg}
      />
      <View style={chartWrapperStyle}>
        <AreaChart
          style={chartStyle}
          data={data}
          contentInset={verticalContentInset}
          curve={shape.curveCatmullRom}
          svg={{ fill: '#FF4D4D' }}
          animate
        />
        <View style={xAxisStyle}>
          {
            timeSpan !== 'Month' && (
              <XAxis
                data={data}
                // formatLabel={(value, index) => months[value]}
                formatLabel={(value, index) => xAxisPoints[index]}
                contentInset={{ left: 10, right: 10 }}
                // numberOfTicks={5}
                svg={axesSvg}
              />
            )
          }
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
```

The style for the chart is as follows.

```
  containerStyle: {
    height: 200,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  yAxisStyle: {
    // marginBottom: 20,
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 180,
    left: 20,
    zIndex: 2,
  },
  chartStyle: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  chartWrapperStyle: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  xAxisStyle: {
    marginHorizontal: -5,
    height: 20,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm testing this as isolated and only component on screen everything seems to work properly on Android (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2). Try to isolate this component and see if it will work for you on Android, maybe other components affect it. Also you could try to check if container component (with dropDownStyle) has some height or try to set 100%.

Comment: Could you insert some more code including this chart component?